# How to use Azure DevOps with the GitHub repository?

Tags: github, azure-devops

I want to use Azure DevOps for managing, build, deploy and test and GitHub for manage my code.

After i added my GitHub connection and imported my repository from GitHub it seems there is a new clone under https://xxx.visualstudio.com.
If i change my code on GitHub than the code in Azure DevOps not change.

It is possible to link the GitHub repository from Azure DevOps so that there are not 2 repositorys?
Or is it now best practice that when i want use Azure DevOps i should also use repository from Azure DevOps and not GitHub anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I think you imported the repository, that is not needed if you want to manage the code on GitHub but build it using Azure Devops.

You can create an Azure Devops pipeline to build and deploy your GitHub based code as shown in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Have you thought about [GitHub actions](https://github.com/features/actions) to build, deploy and test your code?